# Oracle reports builder, printing on last page

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I have margin and inside it is a frame that contains a few lines for signatures, but I want it to only be visible on the last page.

So I set it to print on last page, horizontal to variable; but I thought I'd need to add a format trigger on the frame inside the margin. What should I write in pl/sql to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a frame to only print on the last page, don't put it in the margin. Instead, put it below all other frames and (as you already have) set it to print only on the last page.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you put in Margin is always displayed on all pages. Simply move your signature frame to the main layout, below your main group frame. And set it to display on last page only. I assume your signature query is separate query that may or may not be related to other queries... You may keep it inside the main group frame making signature frame variable, for example. It all depends on your design and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now,  there is button in toolbar edit margin, and u can edit everything inside margin. so i put frame inside it and in properties change last page and it worked as i wanted to work. THanks on your replies.